# Get files (other than text) from .zip with libzip

Tags: c++, zip, extract, zlib

I am learning C++ and decided to train me by making a little program that extract files from zip, like text files, images, or even other zip files (but I don't want to extract them directly, one thing a time) with the libzip library.
So I made my program, but now I have a problem.
It extracts well text files, but not files like images or zip. It detects them, gives me exact names and sizes, but once extracted, they are just a few bytes. (but they are located where they should).

Here is my code: http://pastie.org/6221955

So if someone could help me to extract files that aren't texts from zip, it would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading and writing binary data as a textual string. The problem is that strings use the presence of a NULL character (0-byte) to indicate end-of-string. Binary data can (and definitely does) contain zeros all over the place, not just at the end.

You need to use `ofstream`'s `.write (buffer, <size in bytes>)` to write to the disk; by manually specifying the size in bytes, you force it read that many bytes instead of stopping at the first instance of a NULL character.

Comment: Don't forget to open with `ios::base::binary` too otherwise newlines (which aren't actually newlines in binary data) could get converted.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the << operator. You output a character array /  string. Strings in C are null terminated. Thus the first binary 0 will terminate your output.